# How to set a TypeFace to PagerTabStrip text views

Tags: android, custom-font

In my app I'm using a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with a [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) and I need to set custom fonts to my widgets. To set a font for a `Button` or a `TextView` I just extend the class and set a typeface.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initCustomFont();
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initCustomFont();
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initCustomFont();
    }

    private void initCustomFont() {
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/boton_regular.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't use this method for a `PagerTabStrip`. Is there another way to set a typeface that can be used with `PagerTabStrip`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A little late but here is one solution. Get the child views of the PagerTabStrip and check if it is an instance of a TextView. If it is, set the typeface:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pagerTabStrip.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = pagerTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
    if (nextChild instanceof TextView) {
       TextView textViewToConvert = (TextView) nextChild;
       textViewToConvert.setTypeface(PUT_TYPEFACE_HERE)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ugly but so far probably the quickest solution possible. Thanks =)

Comment: I agree but I could not think of another solution other than grabbing the source code directly and modifying it. There is no supported api to directly change the typeface of a PagerTabStrip.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the `PagerTabStrip` with **Hierarchy View** (in Eclipse open Hierarchy View perspective when you run the application) and search for its children. One must be a `TextView` that holds the tab's title. Get this `TextView` and set its typeface.